# MYSQL JSON field WHERE begins or ends with

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

```
'{"city": "Gradystad"}'
```

**This Works**

```
`fields`->'$."city"' LIKE '%stad%' // contains
```

**This Does Not**

```
`fields`->'$."city"' LIKE 'Grady%' // begins with
`fields`->'$."city"' LIKE '%stad' // ends with
```

Why? & How to work around?

Answer (score 0):

Check the capitals on the like function string. It may be a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses the `->` JSON selector syntax in the MySQL Grammar, like documented in the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html)

```
mysql> SELECT c, c->"$.id", g
     > FROM jemp
     > WHERE c->"$.id" > 1
     > ORDER BY c->"$.name";
+-------------------------------+-----------+------+
| c                             | c->"$.id" | g    |
+-------------------------------+-----------+------+
| {"id": "3", "name": "Barney"} | "3"       |    3 |
| {"id": "4", "name": "Betty"}  | "4"       |    4 |
| {"id": "2", "name": "Wilma"}  | "2"       |    2 |
+-------------------------------+-----------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, it does not add `JSON_UNQUOTE` or any method to remove the double quotes from the result set. Since the `where` clauses are evaluated via MySQL (PDO must strip them in the result set conversion) we need to include the extra `"`'s in our search values.